# Calculating elapsed time between button press in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the time between when button is pushed for the first and second time. Performing arithmetic on a single variable works fine (ie. end-1) but if I try to do (end - start), the result is NaN. Have I missed something simple here? Thank you.

```js
function pressButton() {
  let start;
  let end;
  if (timerControl.innerHTML == "Start") {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Stop";
    start = Date.now();
    console.log(start);
  } else {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Start";
    end = Date.now();
    console.log(end);
  }
  let timeElapsed = (end - start);
  console.log(timeElapsed);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pressButton()" id="timerControl">Start</button>
```

Comment: every time you run your function, you recreate `start` and `end`. Only one of your if-statement blocks will run, so you'll be left with `start` or `end` as `undefined`. Trying to do subtraction with `undefined` will result in `NaN`

Comment: As @nick said, try using global variables and use params in your function, and passe those global variable when you call your function.

Comment: For a better precision, if you measure in the same session, I recommend using `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()`. (in the same session because it's not a timestamp, it measures from the js session start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your two local variables **start** and **end** inside the pressButton() function.

When you first click on your button this condition will evaluate to true:

```
 if (timerControl.innerHTML == "Start")
```

This means the variable start will have a value

```
 start = Date.now();
```

The second time the pressButton function gets called the else block of the if-condition gets executed. Unfortunately though you lost the value of the start variable since you've re-defined it initially using:

```
  let start;
```

If you make **start** and **end** global variables instead it will work flawlessly.

```js
let end;
let start;

function pressButton() {
  if (timerControl.innerHTML == "Start") {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Stop";
    start = Date.now();
    console.log(start);
  } else {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Start";
    end = Date.now();
    console.log(end);
    let timeElapsed = (end - start);
    console.log(timeElapsed);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pressButton()" id="timerControl">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring start and end every time the button is clicked irrespective of "STOP" or "START". Also you are calculating the timeElapsed before end is even assigned a value.

```js
let start=0;
let end=0;
let timeElapsed;
function pressButton() {
  if (timerControl.innerHTML == "Start") {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Stop";
    start = Date.now();
    timeElapsed = 0;
    console.log("Start:"+start);
  } else {
    timerControl.innerHTML = "Start";
    end = Date.now();
    console.log("end:"+end);
    timeElapsed = (end - start);
  }
  console.log("timeElapsed:"+timeElapsed);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="pressButton()" id="timerControl">Start</button>
```